# what exactly happened to the sorcerer?

Tags: meaning

I don't understand the meaning of 'broken into' in this sentence. what exactly happened to the sorcerer? The sentences from the end of the THE BRONZE RING story, and i think it talks about punishment of some kind, but i don't know exactly what it is.

**'The next day the sorcerer, tied to the tail of a savage mule loaded with nuts, was broken into as many pieces as there were nuts upon the mule's back.'**

Comment: Don't confuse this meaning, "The vase was *broken* into (small/large) pieces," with "When the family return from holiday, they found that their house had been *broken into*." To *break into a house/safe* means to enter/open it by force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key phrase here is "*broken into pieces*". The sorcerer was tied to a savage animal and the animal then presumably rampaged around until the sorcerer's body was destroyed into very many small parts. There were as many pieces of his body as there were nuts placed on the mule.